# Angular v8 - @ViewChild static true or false

Tags: angular, angular8, viewchild

Angular v8 has just been released. Although it's mostly backward compatible, there's some Breaking Changes.

According to Angular's [Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1) one core change is (and I quote):

#### *"In Angular version 8, it's required that all @ViewChild and @ContentChild queries have a 'static' flag specifying whether the query is 'static' or 'dynamic'."*

It's also state that in most cases just setting `{ static: false }` will do the trick.

```
@ViewChild('selectorName', { static: false }) varName: any;
```

My question is when should I set this attribute (static) to be `true`? and how will it effect my application???

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use `{ static: true }` when you want to access the `ViewChild` in `ngOnInit`.

Use `{ static: false }` will be accessible only in `ngAfterViewInit`. This is also what you want to do for when you have a structural directive (`*ngIf` etc.) in your template.

In most cases `{ static: false }` will work.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss']
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit
{
  @ViewChild('elementA', { static: true }) elementStatic: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
  @ViewChild('elementB', { static: false }) elementDynamic: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
        
  public ngOnInit(): void
  {
    this.elementStatic.nativeElement; // Ok
    this.elementDynamic.nativeElement; // ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined 
  }
  
  public ngAfterViewInit(): void
  {
    this.elementStatic.nativeElement; // Ok
    this.elementDynamic.nativeElement; // Ok
  }
}
```

```html
<div #elementA>A</div>
<div #elementB>B</div>
```

> **Update:** Starting from Angular v9.x static has a default value of ***false***.
> Read more at: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#viewchild

Comment: I would like to correct that for the case of `@ContentChild` the non-static is available in `ngAfterContentInit`

Comment: What's the downside of the old @ViewChild than the new @ViewChild? I feel the previous one is more helpful than in today's update

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation:

> How do I choose which static flag value to use: true or false?
>
> In the
> official API docs, we have always recommended retrieving query results
> in ngAfterViewInit for view queries and ngAfterContentInit for content
> queries. This is because by the time those lifecycle hooks run, change
> detection has completed for the relevant nodes and we can guarantee
> that we have collected all the possible query results.
>
> Most applications will want to use {static: false} for the same
> reason. This setting will ensure query matches that are dependent on
> binding resolution (e.g. results inside *ngIfs or *ngFors) will be
> found by the query.
>
> There are rarer cases where {static: true} flag might be necessary
> (see answer here).

https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration

Comment: Thanks for this, but can you please write an answer, with **explanations**. And not just copy-n-paste a part of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

When to use `{static:true}`

https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration#should-i-use-static-true

This explains in very simple terms.